# How to set npm auth token programmatically in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Hi guys I'm trying to authenticate myself on my own Artifact registry using npm programmatically and a bare token,

```
 npm.load((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('ERR: Loading NPM', err.message);
    reject(err);
  }
  npm.config.set(
    'registry',
    'https://bs-widgets-xxxxxxxxxx.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/npm/widgets/',
  );
  npm.config.set('_auth', 'restricted');
  npm.config.set('_authToken', `${token.authorizationToken}`);
  npm.config.set('always-auth', 'true');
  console.log(npm.config.list);
  console.log('INSTALLING: ', libVersion);
  console.log('TOKEN: ', token);
  npm.commands.install([`${libVersion}`], (er, data) => {
     if (er) {
       console.log('ERR: Installing NPM', er.message);
       reject(er);
     }
     console.log('INSTALLED: ', libVersion);
     resolve(data);
   });
  npm.on('log', (message) => {
    // log the progress of the installation
    console.log('INSTALLING LOGS', message);
  });
});
```

But I'm facing this error:

```
Unable to authenticate, need: Bearer realm="bs-widgets/widgets", Basic realm="bs-widgets/widgets"
```

Looks like npm do not identify my Token

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do that:

```
npm.load((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('ERR: Loading NPM', err.message);
    reject(err);
  }
  npm.config.set(
    'registry',
    'https://bs-widgets-xxxxxxxxxx.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/npm/widgets/',
  );
         
    npm.config.set(
      '//bs-widgets-xxxxxxxxxxxx.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/npm/widgets/:always-auth',
      true,
    );
    npm.config.set(
      '//bs-widgets-xxxxxxxxxxx.d.codeartifact.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/npm/widgets/:_authToken',
      `${ArtFactToken.authorizationToken}`,
    );
  
  npm.commands.install([`${libVersion}`], (er, data) => {
     if (er) {
       console.log('ERR: Installing NPM', er.message);
       reject(er);
     }
     console.log('INSTALLED: ', libVersion);
     resolve(data);
   });
  npm.on('log', (message) => {
    // log the progress of the installation
    console.log('INSTALLING LOGS', message);
  });
});
```